# обновление данных в datagridview после выполнения запроса в access c#

Tags: c#, база-данных, access, datagridview

Подключаю бд к datagridview:

```
`con = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0; Data Source=" + filename);
            con.Open();
            da = new OleDbDataAdapter("select*from Ученики", con);
            ds = new DataSet();
            OleDbCommandBuilder bulder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(da);
            da.UpdateCommand = bulder.GetUpdateCommand();
            da.InsertCommand = bulder.GetInsertCommand();
            da.DeleteCommand = bulder.GetDeleteCommand();
            da.Fill(ds);
            bs = new BindingSource(ds, ds.Tables[0].TableName);
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;`
```

Потом отправляю запрос на добавления данных:

```
     ` string query = "INSERT INTO Ученики (Индификатор, №, ФИО, Конкурсы, Дата_рождения, Снилс, Адрес) VALUES ('" + textIndef.Text + "', '" + textN.Text + "', '" + textFIO.Text + "', '" + textKonkurs.Text + "', '" + textData.Text + "', '" + textSnils.Text + "', '" + textAdres.Text + "')";
OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, con);
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();`
```

Потом обновляю datagridview:

```
 ` da.Fill(ds);
    dataGridView1.DataSource = bs;`
```

Таблица обновляется, но после обновления дублируются те данные, которые в ней уже были
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможно чистить перед заполнением? `dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
dataGridView1.Refresh();`

Comment: Источник привязки нужно заблаговременно очистить `bs.Clear()`

Comment: dataGridView1.Rows.Clear(); dataGridView1.Refresh(); Это не работает проверял.

Comment: Bulson, спасибо за подсказку, только Bindingsource не получится очистить, но я почистил datasource и все получилось

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Источник привязки нужно заблаговременно очистить ds.Clear()